# Ajax send info to php

Tags: php

So. my ajax does not send info to php. Whats wrong over here?

```
    $(document).on('change', '#kasutaja', function(){
    $(this).attr('data-id'); 
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    url: "data/action.php",
    data: "change" : "kasutaja",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      },error: function(data){
            //console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This script has to send info to php to take user from dropdown. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
data: { "change" : "kasutaja" },
```

you are providing a data object. [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Console still saying: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: This also, `$(this).attr('data-id'); `, isn't achieving anything - you aren't doing anything with the value.

Comment: line 5, data/action.php

Comment: How i can to do this then? maybe you can help me?

Comment: You are missing a comma on the previous line.

Comment: I haven't write php for this. How i can start? My goal is if you take some name from dropdown then he fill give this name data from database, i have done html, php(to get names) and now js working, last thing is to make php. How i should do it?

Comment: You haven't written the PHP?! That is far too broad a question for stackoverflow; it isn't a question, it is a request for a tutor.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` is not correct so you just need to send it properly.

```
data: "change" : "kasutaja"
```

Should be

```
data:{"change":"kasutaja"},
```